# Reaching value from sub

Tags: reactjs, three.js, dat.gui

I'm playing around with the Three.js & Dat.gui libraries and would like to reach the values from my **GUIController** inside my **startAnimationLoop()**

**GUIController**

```
import * as dat from 'dat.gui';

export default ({ gui, title }) => {
     var gui = new dat.GUI();
     var controls = function() {
     this.RotationSpeed = 0.005;
    }

     var title = new controls();
     gui.add(title, 'RotationSpeed', 0.005, 0.1);
}
```

Importing and initializing the import inside my **Main.js** file.
The visuals show up as they should.

```
import GUIController from './GUIController'

  componentDidMount() {
    this.sceneSetup();
    addMesh2({ scene: this.scene, cube: this.tableBoard });
    addLights({ scene: this.scene });
    GUIController({gui: this.gui, title: this.title})
    this.startAnimationLoop();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleWindowResize);
  }
```

**startAnimationLoop** function that takes care of all animations(Inside Main.js). I want the values to come from the GUIController.title.RotationSpeed.

```
  startAnimationLoop = () => {
    const tableBoard = this.scene.getObjectByName('tableSurface');
    tableBoard.rotation.y += 0.005; //THIS WORKS
    tableBoard.rotation.y += this.GUIController.title.RotationSpeed; //DOES NOT WORK
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.startAnimationLoop);
  };
```

I believe that the issue is that only the visual part applies, but the values are never sent.

**Console.log inside the GUIController.JS**

```
console.log(title.RotationSpeed) //outputs: 0.005 (the wanted value)
```

**Console.log inside the Main.JS**

```
console.log(this.GUIController.title.RotationSpeed) //outputs: undefined
```

But when i console log just the import it displays the following below:

```
console.log(this.GUIController)
```

[image: console.log]

How do i reach the values in **GUIController.js** from **Main.js** ?

Comment: it seems your `this.GUIController` is still a function? maybe new it first so you can use it as an object like `this.GUIController.title.RotationSpeed`

Answer (score 1):

GUIController

```
import * as dat from 'dat.gui';

export default ({ gui, title }) => {
     var gui = new dat.GUI();
     var controls = function() {
     this.RotationSpeed = 0.005;
    }

     var title = new controls();
     gui.add(title, 'RotationSpeed', 0.005, 0.1);
}
```

here you passed a title instance as parameter, but then you declared another one and replace it, could this be the cause?

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake. i had an equal variable in the file that i forgot to comment out. it's stil undefined.